# "Not found: URI gs://" Error when File actually exists in the bucket URI

Tags: json, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage

I have three json files (customers,salesorders,products)that load from GCS bucket to Bigquery, all of a sudden the customer file is not loading to the table, whereas salesorder and products files are loaded without errors.

I tried via UI,BQ CLI and Python Client.

**Here are the errors:**
**Cloud UI** : *Not found: URI gs://*

**BQ CLI** : *BigQuery error in load operation: Error processing job 'job ID': Not found: URI gs://..*

**via Python Client :**
*400 Error while reading data, error message: JSON table encountered too many errors, giving up. Rows: 1; errors: 1. Please look into the errors[] collection for more details.*

Could it be some sort of permission issue or system error?

Comment: Can you check in the activity log if something has changed in your project? A bucket deleted? Some permissions removed?...

Comment: Yes, that was a permission issue that changed at Infra level.